# I need a WordPress plugin that can create an IDE for codes to run on my website

Tags: wordpress, ide, wordpress-plugin-creation, code-editor

I have a WordPress site, and I teach python on it and I want to share some code on it. I want a code editor that users can see my code and run it.
Please if you know any plugin that can do this help me.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not think that there is such kind of a plugin available as of now. However, you can always search for such a plugin inside the official WordPress plugin repository.

Still, my recommendation would be to consider building your custom website ( not based on WordPress at all ) in order to achieve that using a different application or framework that has already developed a tool for that purpose.